What does 流れでは！？ mean at the end of this sentence?
Dungeon Meshi episode 23, in order to test if a meat stew that センシ was fed years ago by his fellow dwarves to survive was not made of one of his party members, but was actually meat of a hippogriff, ライオス proposes that they search for a hippogriff, but マルシル raises doubts on their ability to find one:

ライオス: それじゃあ確かめようか。
実際にヒポグリフの肉と食べ比べるんだ。
マルシル: そ　そこは➡
「真相は不明だけど
いちるの希望は出たね」で➡
やんわり終わる流れでは！？
Let's compare this with a taste of some
Hippogriff meat.
Hey, wait a minute!
Aren't you supposed to say, "The
truth is still unknown, but at least there's a ray of hope," and end
it there? [show's translation]

I know that 流れ here means something like a "current of events", but where I struggle is how this fits in the sentence.
I assume this is a shortening of 流れではない！？, but it seems then to come together as something like:

"As for that point raised, is it not a course of events where it ends
mildly like "the truth is unknown but a sliver of hope came out right?"

I don't know if my understanding of 流れ is correct here, and more importantly, if my parsing is okay, how does " is it not a course of events" even work in this sentence? Is this an example where it would make more sense to think of it as a future action, like "won't it be a course of events where..."?  ー＞ "won't it end up that..."
But if that makes sense, I honestly would expect something like this instead to convey a change like that:

。。。やんわり終わる流れにならない！？

1.) I wonder how to most accurately interpret this usage of 流れ.
2.) I also want to know why "is it not a course of events that...?" could be thought of as something like "won't it turn out that...?", because that is not intuitive to me. [how is the usage in the episode different from 流れにならない！？]

I think your understanding is spot on. では here is short for tag question ender ではないか.

The nuance of a "current/flow" being associated with "what is expected" seems to be seen elsewhere, e.g. in the gikun [流石]{さすが}.

^ 「流石」って、中国の故事『石に枕し流れに漱ぐ』の言い間違い（『流れに枕し石に漱ぐ』なんて！さすが！）から来てるから、flow/current → what is expected とは関係ないのでは…

You have parsed the sentence correctly, but you seem to have missed an important connotation of the word 流れ. The flow of the river always moves in one direction. Similarly, 流れ used metaphorically like this has a connotation of natural or expected flow of events even without sayin 自然な explicitly. For example, 会話の流れを無視する人 refers to someone who does not follow the natural flow of a conversation.
